Is it possible to have Llama-2's vocabulary file?
I am looking for Llama-2's vocabulary list to do preliminary research. I tried to search on Google, but couldn't find any results.


Is it possible to have Llama-2's vocabulary file?

To list all tokens, use get_vocab:
from transformers import LlamaTokenizer
token = "<your_token_here>" # Get token on https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(“meta-llama/Llama-2-70b-chat-hf”, token=token)
tokenizer.get_vocab()

Note that tokens in Llama aren't words but subwords, since the Llama tokenizer uses Byte-Pair Encoding (BPE).

Is there any way to access vocab without having a license? I would need vocabulary and not the weights.

@MehdiAbbassi afaik vocab is also under license from a legal standpoint. But from a tech standpoint, always workarounds, eg torrents.

@MehdiAbbassi cool! Yes it's not too hard to get it :) unless you're TikTok CEO or some other business with a very large user base.
